# SQL Server - find a letter in a chain which doesn't belong to anyone

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-analysis

I have a query which takes itemnum and search the table to find the itemnum which doesn't have any replacementItemNum in a chain.

It is like a chain where a belong to b and b belongs c , need to find the letter in a chain which doesn't belong to anyone.

Table has 72k records.

- If I pass A or B or C, I will get letter D because it doesn't have any replacement item.
- If I pass D, then result would be NULL

This is how the data (chain) looks like:

```
ItemNum - ReplacementItemNum
----------------------------    
    A     -  B
    B     -  C
    C     -  D
    D     -
```

This query is taking too long; can this be re written so it doesn't take that long?

```
DECLARE @CountryOID INT = 250 ,
        @ItemNum VARCHAR(50) = 'A';

DECLARE @LastItem VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @NextItem VARCHAR(50);

SELECT @LastItem = ReplaceItemNum
FROM dbo.MacInventory
WHERE ItemNum = @ItemNum
  AND CountryOID = @CountryOID;

WHILE @LastItem <> ''
BEGIN
    SET @NextItem = @LastItem;

    SELECT @LastItem = ReplaceItemNum
    FROM dbo.MacInventory
    WHERE ItemNum = @LastItem
      AND CountryOID = @CountryOID;
END;

SELECT @NextItem;
```

Comment: I guess recursive CTE would perform better than loop - http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CTEs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Recursive cte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) to the rescue!

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ItemNum char(1),
    ReplacementItemNum char(1)
);

INSERT INTO @T (ItemNum, ReplacementItemNum) VALUES
('A', 'B'), 
('B', 'C'),
('C', 'D'),
('D', NULL),
('E', 'F'), -- added some more data to make sure we don't get the wrong result...
('F', NULL);
```

Set your starting point:

```
DECLARE @StartFrom char(1) = 'A';
```

The recursive cte:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ItemNum, ReplacementItemNum
    FROM @T
    WHERE ItemNum = @StartFrom

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T.ItemNum, T.ReplacementItemNum
    FROM @T As T
    JOIN CTE 
        ON T.ItemNum = CTE.ReplacementItemNum
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT IIF(ItemNum = @StartFrom, NULL, ItemNum) As ItemNum
FROM CTE
WHERE ReplacementItemNum IS NULL
```

And finally, the result:

```
ItemNum
D
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/JIFQ59943)

Comment: If i pass D then result would be NULL.

Comment: Easy. Updated the answer and the live demo.

Comment: query works but it is taking same time as my other query :(

Comment: Table has 72k records.

Comment: Any indexes on the relevant columns? Did you check the execution plan?

Comment: There is an index on itemnum and countryOID and ReplaceItemNum. I am also getting error The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 32767 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: the error can easily be fixed using the `MAXRECURSION(0)` query hint. However, the slowness of the query is a different story. you should check the execution plan to see where the bottle necks are. One thing that might help performance is to insert the all `ItemNum` and `ReplacementItemNum` data for the specified `CountryOID` into an indexed temporary table and select from that table. That might help but only if the countryOID` is the first column in at least one index on the table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196663/discussion-between-user1263981-and-zohar-peled).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have proper indexes on the column (CountryOID, ItemNum) in the table? Try the following recursive cte solution:

```
;WITH cte_item (ItemNum, ReplaceItemNum)
AS
(
SELECT ItemNum, ReplaceItemNum
FROM dbo.MacInventory
WHERE   ItemNum = @ItemNum
AND CountryOID = @CountryOID
UNION
SELECT m.ItemNum, m.ReplaceItemNum
FROM dbo.MacInventory m
INNER JOIN cte_item i
ON m.ItemNum = i.ReplaceItemNum 
AND m.CountryOID = @CountryOID
)
SELECT * FROM cte_item WHERE ReplaceItemNum='';
```

Comment: should be fixed. Sorry, I can't test it.